I'm stuck on Ubuntu Installation of ROS Noetic (there is an error about Curl package having no installation candidate)
i've been following installation steps from http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu but stucked at step 1.3 because of this error below:
james@James:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
[sudo] password for james: 
james@James:~$ sudo apt install curl # if you haven't already installed curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate**
james@James:~$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK
james@James:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease                       
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
james@James:~$

i tried to update it using 'sudo apt update' and it updated, but when i try the 'sudo apt install curl' code again it still doesn't fix the problem. is there anything i can do to fix this? (i'm using Ubuntu 20.04.6)
update:
...
All packages are up to date.
james@James:~$ sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-noetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-noetic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


I guess curl is now in one of the core packages in Ubuntu, and this line shows you that curl is working james@James:~$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add - OK  you should be able to continue the tutorial.

but when i tried to continue the tutorial it just said that i have held broken packages (as in the post's update)

what happens if you type only sudo apt install -y ros-noetic-desktop?

it gave me this error message: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
